# “seguro morreu de velho”. E o provérbio, também morreu?

Tags: proverbios

**“seguro morreu de velho”** era um provérbio muito comum em pt-BR, nos anos 50 e 60 do século passado.  Ouvi essas palavras tantas vezes (1 e 2), ditas por meus avós, que nunca foi preciso que alguém me explicasse seu significado literal (3) ou literário (4)

> 1. “Não deixe seus brinquedos na calçada. Vá busca-los, meu filho. Seguro morreu de velho”.
> 2. “Sim, vou trancar todas as janelas de casa. Sei que não vamos demorar muito, mas seguro morreu de velho.”
> 3. “um indivíduo precavido, morrerá de velhice e não de outras causas que abreviem sua vida.”
> 4. “Quem se previne evita surpresas desagradáveis”.

Com seu significado literário (4), o provérbio pode ser usado em qualquer situação onde queremos dizer que “com sabedoria, toma-se precauções para evitar surpresas desagradáveis.”
Pergunto então:

- a origem do provérbio é portuguesa ou brasileira?
- Ainda é usado em Portugal ou no Brasil nos dias de hoje?
- Seu significado é entendido por jovens? (digamos, indivíduos com menos de 25 anos de idade)
- “seguro”, nesse caso em particular, é um substantivo?   Mas o único significado de seguro como substantivo que encontro no Aurélio, refere-se às companhias de seguro (“seguro de vida”, “seguro contra furto”, etc)  Como explicar?

Comment: Eu ouço aqui em São Paulo (Brasil), algumas pessoas mais velhas usarem este provérbio, mas não é tão comum como antes. Achei estas imagens interessantes: http://www.saopauloantiga.com.br/seguro-morreu-de-velho/

Comment: @sumitani   ótimas !

Comment: Eu nunca tinha visto essa expressão. Acredito que um jovem entenda. Não me enquadro na sua definição de jovem por pouco :-)

Comment: @Centaurus pareceu-me que a resposta não respondeu nem a metade da sua pergunta. Você sabe que pode deixar perguntas sem o visto, certo? É que meter o visto de certo desencoraja novas respostas... É apenas uma nota e não um crítica.

Comment: @sumitani   Ótimas as figuras dos bondes.

Comment: O seguro é morrer de velho. Aqui a frase tem seu sentido lato. Precaução... Ser precavido... Morrer de velho....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Não sei a origem da expressão.
- A expressão ainda é usada em Portugal, hoje em dia. Mas nós usamos com artigo definido: `o seguro morreu de velho`.
- Em Portugal, por ainda ser usado, eu esperaria que o seu significado fosse entendido.
- Em Portugal, por ter o artigo, é clara e obviamente um substantivo.
  Uma das definições no priberam<sup>1</sup> `(14) Amparo; protecção; salvaguarda.` encaixa bem neste caso, e é com esse significado que eu entendo a expressão: "*o seguro*" como "*a segurança*" ou "*o estar seguro*".
  *Cautela e caldos de galinha, nunca fizeram mal a ninguém*...

---

[1] "seguro", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://priberam.pt/dlpo/seguro [consultado em 17-10-2016].

Comment: +1  Já no lado de cá do Atlântico, nós dizemos "caldo de galinha" no singular.

Comment: Poderia ser a personificação do adjetivo seguro?

Comment: Sim, @Centaurus, concordo!

Comment: "o seguro" = 'o [homem] seguro'