# The expression "pois é"?

Tags: expressões, tradução

I live in São Paulo although I'm an American and teach English here. One of my most troublesome questions is how to translate "pois é"?? Google gives me YEAH, or IT IS. Are there broader or more subtle translations? More idiomatic usage?

Comment: Yes, well [rest of sentence]. Yes, right, [rest of conversation. It does NOT translate to YEAH or IT IS. That is just crap. Think of this: Mario: Eu fui a praia com ele ontém. João: Pois é, foi o que pensei. Right, that's what I thought. Most of the time, it just means WELL. Well, that's what I thought [too].

Comment: Sometimes, it is also used to mark a difference with what the first speaker is saying.  Then, it's translated as WELL. Porqué você chegou atrasada na festa? [seg. pessoa] Pois é, não cheguei atrasada, só que você não mi viu. Well, I didn't get there late, you just didn't see me.

Comment: @Lambie I strongly disagree: "<A> O Presidente do [clube de futebol] é um corrupto... <B> Pois é!".

Comment: @Lambie Please avoid answering in comments. `Use the comments to ask for more information or to suggest improvements to the question`.

Comment: @ANeves Yes, but that is at the end of a sentence. B) So he is! I didn't cover every single case.

Comment: Apparently I'm seven years late to this party, but ‍♂️. Re: pois é - can it have a similar tone/meaning as how we say "shit happens" in response to something negative but of which we (the listener) don't really care about or have no vested interest in? I.e:
Bob: "Oh man! I got a coffee stain on my favorite shirt!"
Bill: "... Shit happens, dude ..."

Comment: I hope it adds to the question: https://youtu.be/Nw9zXKC-zDA This is a car seller TV advertisement from the 1980s in São Paulo where the expression "Pois é..." was used in several ways(The company no longer operates.).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**"*Pois é*" is an interjection phrase** and its translation depends pretty much on context.  Basically it expresses **confirmation** or **resignation**, or both simultaneously. Sometimes it's just a filler. Other times you'd better ignore it in a translation work. In pt-BR you're likely to find it in sentences such as:

> 1. (a) "Não se pode mais fazer bater nos filhos?"
>    (b) "**Pois é**, agora as coisas mudaram."  (**"That's it", "that's true", "yes, you're right"** or simply **"yes"**).
> 2. (a) "Vamos ou não vamos ter um aumento salarial?"
>    (b) "**Pois é**, conforme eu havia dito na reunião anterior, a situação financeira da empresa está indefinida no momento e..." ("pois é" here sounds more like a **filler**, something like "vejam só" or "olhem". It may be translated as **"you see"**, **"look here"**, **"well"**).
> 3. (a) "Que droga de tempo.  Chuva o tempo todo."
>    (b) **"Pois é"**. (**agreed, I agree, exactly**, said with regret) — In this example, intonation is everything so that it may even sound like **"told you"** or **"too bad"**.
> 4. (a) "Você está dizendo que ele morreu?"
>    (b) **"Pois é**, morreu ontem". (**exactly, yes, that's it**).

As I've said before, "*pois é*" is an interjection phrase that **expresses confirmation or resignation**. More frequently it can be translated into English as **"yes", "agreed", "exactly", "it's true", "you're right", that's it"**.  Remember that interjections are unique in that more often than not you can hardly find a perfect translation, especially in the written language where stress and intonation are absent.

NB

1. When in Portugal, beware of "*pois*", "*pois é*", "*ora pois*", "*ora pois pois*". These are used much more frequently in pt-PT than in pt-BR, sometimes as a filler, and with different meanings.
2. Don't confuse "*pois é*" (interjection) with "*pois é*" (two words meaning "*porque é*"). Example:

> "O empreendedorismo é essencial nas sociedades, **pois é**  (porque é) através dele que as empresas buscam a inovação."

To be more precise, "*pois é*", the same way as "*muito bem!*", "*que alívio*", "*é isso aí, mano*", "*nossa mãe!*", "*de jeito nenhum*", etc. **is an interjection phrase**, in the sense that it has the meaning of a complete sentence and is thus understood.

Comment: Frankly, Pois é is mostly the idea of  /Well, the thing is that/. In English, we don't start sentences "in response" with some of the words you have given. Pois é can be: Well// or  /Well, the thing is that//Yes, that's right [not you're right] or /well, right/ I would not say exactly for it in English.  **It is not an interjection.** It is a conversational discourse marker re the other person. Sometimes, it does not even require translation.

Comment: @Lambie  In a particular context  "póis é" can be translated as "you're right".  You've also mentioned that it isn't an interjection.  "You're right", I wasn't accurate enough. In **Portuguese** it is "uma locução interjetiva".

Comment: Póis é, geralmente não quer dizer você está certo ou você tem razão. So se diz póis é respondendo a outro falante. Pouco importa a gramática em si para poder traduzir a expressão. As vezes se usa até para completar ou adicionar um ideia completamente diferente....

Comment: @Lambie Em Portugal, **usa-se** "pois é" como resposta confirmativa (?!?). Para outras coisas também, mas também para dizer (e passo a citar) "você está certo ou você tem razão".

Comment: @ANeves O **pois** português não é o **pois é** do Brasil. Mas claro, pa, misturemos tudo....

Comment: @Lambie   It isn't different in Brazil.  Depending on **context** and **intonation**, pois é can mean "você está certo" ou "você tem razão".   Translation depends on both context and intonation.  I can say "pois é" in several different ways and my folks here will understand it for what it is.  I just can't cover all of it in one answer and no audio.

Comment: Eu sei perfeitamente o que quer dizer /Pois é/. Eu sou intérprete. E também já passei **muito tempo** em Portugal. Os portugueses costuman dizer, a maior parte das vezes, só /pois/, e não costuman dizer /pois é/ com a mesma frequência que os brasileiros.  É uma das primeiras coisas (características típicas) que se nota ao chegar em Portugal....

Comment: @Lambie  De acordo com seus relatos, o Sr. é intérprete. Fala inglês e português fluentemente.  Conhece bem tanto o portugues falado no Brazil quanto o português Europeu. Sabe perfeitamente o que quer dizer "pois é".  Então, porque não contribui com uma resposta?  Certamente terá muito a acrescentar àquilo que eu pude escrever.

Comment: @Centaurus Sabe porqué? Porque cansa. Cada vez que aparece uma pergunta mais o menos simples, começa a ficar tão complicado que perdo o fôlego e minha paciência. Cheguei atrasada à pergunta....Portugal é um barato mesmo. Ah, e sou senhora, não senhor. :)

Comment: @Lambie não discordo que o "pois é" seja mais usado no Brasil, ou que cá em Portugal usemos mais "pois" do que "pois é". Mas usamos (**[ex. 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOxKVcpzTtk&t=11)**, **[ex. 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qib8WQvmubc)**, etc) de facto essa expressão. Adiciona uma resposta alternativa, [mesmo que seja incompleta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/3758/157), que eu acho sempre bom ter visões complementares ou alternativas.

Comment: A unica coisa que esta faltando nessa resposta e o "Pois é" usado por un segundo locutor em resposta a um comentário de um primeiro locutor. Tambem que em Portugal se costuma dizer mais Pois, do que Pois é.

Answer (score 1):

I think we use "[It is what it is](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/it-is-what-it-is)" the same way folks use "*pois é*". Literally it doesn't mean much, but it's used to signal resignation.

Answer (score 0):

Pois e....means "yeah", but in the sense of "yeah, yeah,that's the way it is, what can you do?" It's almost like saying "that's life". My grandma used to use the expression a lot.