# Qual a classe gramatical, função sintática e significado da palavra "também" nos exemplos abaixo?

Tags: significado-em-contexto, classe-gramatical, função-sintática

- "Eu ganhei mais cinco quilos esse mês. Não sei mais o que fazer."
  "*Também*, você não para de comer doce."
- "Eles sempre fazem cara feia quando eu chego."
  "*Também*, você só sabe falar sobre as suas façanhas. Não fala sobre outra coisa"

O [**Priberam**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/tamb%C3%A9m#:%7E:text=Igualmente%2C%20conjuntamente.,isto%2C%20como%20consequ%C3%AAncia%20de%20tal.) apresenta as seguintes definições:

**advérbio**

1. Do mesmo modo.
2. Igualmente, conjuntamente.

**conjunção**

3. Por isto, como  consequência de tal.

Não me parece que essas definições se apliquem perfeitamente aos exemplos acima.  Qual seria então a classificação gramatical, a função sintática e o significado?

Comment: No primeiro exemplo em "você não para" devia ser "pára" com acento agudo.

Comment: @bad_coder Não desde o acordo de 1990: https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/parar (configure para "depois do acordo").

Comment: @stafusa eu ainda não tinha reparado, o verbete no priberam tem um link para [este artigo](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/4918) e a grafia do AO90 neste caso realmente não faz sentido.

Comment: Esses dois pares de frases não parecem naturais. Generalmente, seria um só locutor OU se dois, precisa de uma certa lógica discursiva. Eu acho que o uso de também nas duas está errado.

Comment: As duas frases não tem nenhum sentido juntas assim.

Comment: @Lambie  As duas frases fazem sentido para milhões e milhões de falantes da língua portuguesa. Lamento que não façam sentido para a senhora.

Comment: Acho que as pessoas não estão lendo **bem"". Como disse na minha resposta: precisa ser dois falantes e não um falante. Você deveria dizer algo como: Falante 1: "Eu ganhei mais cinco quilos esse mês. Não sei mais o que fazer."
Falante 2: "Também, você não para de comer doce." Então, eu tenho toda a razão. E foi o que eu disse na **minha resposta** com um frase um pouco mais comprida.

Comment: Por favor, não me trate de senhora.

Comment: @Lambie  Atente para a pergunta ["The expression pois é"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/the-expression-pois-%c3%a9) de 15 de outubro de 2016. Dirigi-me a vossa senhoria como "o senhor" e obtive a seuinte resposta, que lá se encontra até hoje: "Cheguei atrasada à pergunta....Portugal é um barato mesmo. Ah, e sou senhora, não senhor. :) – 
Lambie.                 Assim sendo, fique tranquila pois passarei a usar um pronome de tratamento de gênero neutro.

Comment: @Lambie   É óbvio que são dois falantes. Mas nada impede que seja uma única pessoa ouvindo a resposta de seu próprio super-ego.

Comment: Eu tive que rele várias vezes. Para mim, nao foi óbvio. Eu falei "sou senhora" para dizer que não sou senhor. E até coloquei um :) Ou seja para dizer que **sou mulher**, não homen. Pronome neutro, não, pelo amor de Deus. Tu  PrP) ou você (PrB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boa parte dos dicionários descrevem "também" nessa acepção como uma **conjunção aditiva**:

[Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/tamb%C3%A9m/):

> **conjunção**
>
> Emprega-se com significação aproximativa ou copulativa de *e*: *Ela chegou na hora determinada pelo pai, também, se não chegasse, ficaria de castigo.*

[dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/tambem/):

> conjunção
>
> E, nem, não; liga termos e/ou orações de mesma função: assinou a confissão, também, se não assinasse, seria preso.

[Houaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v6-1/html/index.php#1):

> **conjunção**
>
> **5** *conjunção aditiva* usada para unir dois termos ou orações de funções iguais; e, nem, e não ‹*falou a verdade, também, se não falasse, seria castigado*›

Mas, na minha opinião, aquele que melhor captura o significado do "também" nesses casos — que leio com a ênfase de "e não poderia ser diferente" ou, como colocado pelo Centaurus, uma entonação de "também pudera" — é o [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/Tamb%C3%A9m):

> **advérbio**
>
> **4**. Usado como reforço explicativo: *Está cansadíssima. **Também**, ficou no baile até de manhã*.

Que esses significados não sejam encontrados no Priberam ou na Infopédia pode indicar que é um uso mais típico do pt-BR.

Comment: E exatamente a este último exemplo que me refiro.  Muito comum em pt-BR;

Comment: Diga-se de passagem que nesse uso de "também", a entonação da voz é um pouco diferente daquela ouvida nos outros usos.  É a mesma entonação de "também pudera".

Comment: @Centaurus Sim. E valeu por me lembrar da intonação, ela é ao meu ver importante também - até incluí agora na resposta.

Comment: Faltou a função sintática.

Comment: Tem razão, @Centaurus , mas por hora vou ficar devendo, porque não consegui encontrar a nomenclatura adequada.

Answer (score -1):

"Eu ganhei mais cinco quilos esse mês. Não sei mais o que fazer."
"Também, você não para de comer doce."

**Não faz sentido a segunda frase acima em uma sequência, ou seja, depois da primeira**.

Assim o faria, por exemplo, **com um locutor**:
"Eu ganhei mais cinco quilos esse mês. Não sei mais o que fazer."
"**Também, acho** que vou [etc]." [o mesmo locutor; conjunção]

**Com dois locutores**:
João: "Eu ganhei mais cinco quilos esse mês. Não sei mais o que fazer."
Marcos: Não me estranha. Você come demais e também não para de comer doce." [advérbio: do mesmo modo]

Agora, se pode aplicar as explicações do Priberam.

Comment: Downvoter: Tsk, tsk. tsk.